# SQL Server : incorrect syntax near Tablockx . Expecting '(' or Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [lot].[wipeAll] 
    @num VARCHAR(16),
    @quotaType INT,
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM @TableName WITH (TABLOCKX) 
    WHERE num = @num AND quotaType = @quotaType;
END
```

I can't figure out how to work around this error I'm getting

> Incorrect syntax near Tablockx . Expecting '(' or Select

from the above code snippet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't parameterize table name like that.

Comment: This is not caused by the hint, remove it and it will still fail. You can't use parameters for object names, this must be dynamic SQL

Comment: Problem occurs because of Table name. you are trying to refer columns that SQL doesn't recognize so that problem returns. give the table name

Comment: @Halilİbrahim, what is the point of removing ; from the end? The problem has nothing to do with columns, no?

Comment: Nvm it was showing me error at the "End".but after correcting table name everything gone fine

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I'll look into dynamic SQL .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
DELETE FROM @TableName WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE num=@num AND quotaType=@quotaType)';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@TableName', @TableName);

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
         '@num varchar(16), @quotaType int',
         @num=@num, @quotaType=quotaType
END;
```